# How to get year from current date on python?

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

I get responses that deliver the whole date, but that adds overhead.

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: `datetime.today().year`

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
this_year=datetime.today().strftime('%Y')
this_year=int(this_year)
```

Anything more simple than that?

Yes, thanks luigigi

```
datetime.today().year
```

Comment: This is better:

import datetime
year = datetime.date.today().year